# How to output the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
new Vue({
  data: {
      ban : [{
          name : 'folder1',
          active : 1,
        },
        {
          name : 'folder2',
          active : 0,
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

How to get the active value without using v-for

I try this way `$ban[0]`
I get the first object, but if I use it, `$ban[0].active` then an error

Comment: Show the html part of the code

Comment: have you tried using the following syntaxt `$ban[0]?.active`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `$ban[0]?.active` or `$ban[0] && $ban[0].active`